# animating an angle of a triangle

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, angle

I have two lines that make a 90 degree angle, I hope. I want to make it so that the vertical line moves down to the horizontal line. The angle is the pivot point. so the angle should decrease to 0 I guess. 45 would be half way.

- the length of the lines should be the same during the animation.
- the animation should be looping. It should go from 90 degree angle to
  0 degree angle and back.

1 way I was thinking to figure this out was to change the `context.moveTo(50,50)` the parameters numbers so the line should begin to be drawn at the new coordinates during the animation. I had problems keeping the line the same size as the horizontal.

another way I was thinking was to change the `Math.atan2`. I don't know have it start at 90 degrees then go to 0 and have that reflect on the moveto parameters I don't know how to put this together.

I would prefer to use a solution with trigonometry because that is what I'm trying to get good at

for extra help if you could attach a hypotenuse so I could see the angle change the size of the triangle that would be great. That was my original problem. Thanks

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas =document.getElementById("canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var length = 50

 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(50,50)
 context.lineTo(50,200);
 context.stroke();
 context.closePath();

 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(50, 200);
 context.lineTo(200, 200)
 context.stroke();
 context.closePath();

 var p1 = {
  x: 50,
  y : 50
 }
 var p2 = {
  x: 50,
  y: 200
 }

 var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
 console.log(angleDeg)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var length = 150;
  var angle = 270;
  var maxAngle = 360;
  var minAngle = 270;
  var direction = 0;
  var p1 = {
    x: 50,
    y: 200
  };
  var p2 = {
    x: 200,
    y: 200
  };
  context.fillStyle = "rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.5)";

  function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    context.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y)


    if (angle >= maxAngle) {
      direction = 1;
    } else if (angle <= minAngle) {
      direction = 0;
    }

    if (direction == 0) {
      angle++;
    } else {
      angle--;
    }

    var x = p1.x + length * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    var y = p1.y + length * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);

    context.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    context.lineTo(x, y);

    context.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);

    context.stroke();
    context.fill()
    context.closePath();
  }

  setInterval(draw, 50);

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get angle sequence (in degrees) like 90-45-0-45-90-45..., you can use this simple algo (pseudocode):

```
i = 0
while (drawingNeeded) do
    angle = Math.Abs(90 - (i % 180)) *  Math.PI / 180;
    endPoint.x = centerPoint.x + lineLength * Math.Cos(angle);
    endPoint.y = centerPoint.y + lineLength * Math.Sin(angle);
    //redraw canvas, draw static objects
    drawLine(centerPoint, endPoint);
    i++;
```